# NextJS calling dynamic page on production redirects to root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

#### What I want

User enters https://www.example.com/test, user gets content of NextJS dynamic route `/test/index.js`.
**This works locally.**

#### What happens

User enters https://www.example.com/test, user gets content of root page (index.js).
The browser still shows https://www.example.com/test but it's not the content of `/test/index.js`. **This only appears on production.**

**Infos**

- Deploying to Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem was, that I was exporting the NextJS application and using the output as source files for Firebase. The solution for my specific problem was, to set up **Firebase functions** to really enable serverside rendering instead of displaying served static files. This also solved my routing problem.

I found tutorials to be very misleading, once everyone uses different folder structures and ways to deploy the application.

If you are facing the same problem, feel free to check out [my repository](https://github.com/aichner/topimmo-front/tree/add-basics-aa1). It is a combination of the Firebase config, package.json and server file working together - taking in account different folder paths for exporting for development and production.

These resources were helpful to me:

Overall Tutorial: https://itnext.io/deploying-next-js-app-to-firebase-functions-eb473791d79e - This is missing some steps regarding function names.

Great for understanding what each file does: https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-gcp-examples/tree/master/functions-nextjs

Nice for understanding ways of rendering: https://codeburst.io/next-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-with-firebase-hosting-7911465298f2

This made me understand how to use Firebase function names correctly: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting